# Locked screen in windows 8 WinRT

Tags: c#-4.0, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

When my app is running in Windows 8 WINRT can I prevent the OS to go to locked screen/sleep mode?

Comment: I don't think so, I think that because this isn't what the user expects to happen whenever they lock their machine, it goes against WinRT app design guidelines, and will be rejected by the Windows Store, even if you got it to work

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the [DisplayRequest class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/windows.system.display.displayrequest) to indicate that you are busy playing back something that requires the display to stay active and un-dimmed.  A good how-to article with sample code is [available here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj152728).  Don't use it frivolously, it is quite detrimental to power consumption.  Good odds that the Store will reject your app if you use it for no obvious benefit to the user.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot prevent OS to go to lock screen/sleep/shut-down etc. If you want your application to run behind the scenes, you may want to create a Background Task application. You can find more information at: [MSDN Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/Hh977056%28v=win.10%29.aspx)