# IdleDetectionMode in Windows 8 SDK

Tags: windows-8, mediaelement

Is there an equivalent to the IdleDetectionMode method in the windows 8 sdk?  I'm trying to figure out how to prevent the screen from locking while playing back video.  I'm assuming that the method would be the same as in windows phone 7.

Comment: Found the answer to the question after some additional searching.  It is the DisplayRequest class in Windows 8.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12758900/locked-screen-in-windows-8-winrt